# Connecting points with line in a specific sequence

Tags: qgis, geometry, connection, virtual-layer, geometry-generator

I have 6 points in one layer as shown in the first image. I am trying to:

1. connect points with lines in a required sequence.
2. Save data of line connections (**From_point** and **To_point**) in the seperate layer.

For demo, I have manually connected the `lines (green)` and shown the `sequence (red)` with numbers in Image 1. The sequence of connecting lines should be as follows:

| Sequence | From_point | To_point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 (building1) to (Junction) | 7b9f | aab4 |
| 2 (building2) to (Junction) | d052 | aab4 |
| 3 (Junction) to (Breaker) | aab4 | edb3 |
| 4 (Breaker) to (Station) | edb3 | c037 |
| 5 (Sation)) to (MainSource) | c037 | 4d3c |

**Initial attempt with points to path:**

I tried to achieve this `Menu Processing / Toolbox / points to path` and `Points2One plugin` but it does not maintain the required sequence of connections as shown in Image 2

[image: ![![![![enter image description here]

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: You're trying to create a multi-line, since there's a branch in it. A multi-line is no path, hence the tool wont "work". You could create all the single line segments and then dissolve them, if you only care about the geometry.

Comment: Is there any rule on how to connect points? The table doesn't give a clue. I understand (from table) that the buildings are connected to junctions. That's fine. But, what if there are many junctions around the buildings?

Comment: @Erik. How about this case https://i.stack.imgur.com/25HKy.png ? I make it simple by removing one building class. The connection sequence is `building- Juntion- breaker-Station-Main source`. Is it possible that `make line` function in geometry generater will connect the line and save the `start` and `ending point` of every line in new layer as I tried to manually show here  https://i.stack.imgur.com/25HKy.png ?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz. If we ignore the sequence, Is it possible to connect points with lines and save the `start data` and `End data` of every line in new layer? For instance, building is connected to junction:attribute 1 in new layer, then junction to breaker: attribute 2 in new layer and so on as I have tried to show here https://i.stack.imgur.com/25HKy.png

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz. The rule is to connect the points according to Id in points layer (ascending order). I mean ID:1 should be connected to ID:2 then ID:2 with ID:3 and so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### All in one solution with virtual layer

For your probleme you can indeed use virtual layer, I didn't know you want use this method :

```sql
with
build_segment as (
select 
  a.mrid as start_point, 
  b.mrid as end_point,
  makeline(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry
from <layername> a
left join <layername> b on (a.id + 1 = b.id  ))

select
  * 
from build_segment
where geometry is not null
```

Answer (score 4):

### Solution with algorithms and expressions

For the fist part of your problem :

You could use the **geometry by expression** algorithm and use this expression :

```
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach(
        aggregate( 
            'LAYERNAME' ,
            'array_agg', 
            "mrid", 
            filter:="id" =  attribute(@parent, 'id')+1),
        make_line($geometry, geometry(get_feature('LAYERNAME', 'mrid',@element)))
    )
)
```

It's not the best approach to what mentioned Kadir. If there are 2 ore more children this expression will build a multilinestring.

For the second part,
apply the **multiparttosinglepart** algorithm on the output of the first treatment. The mrid field correponds to the start and you can obtain the end by adding a new fied on the ouput with this formula :

```
aggregate('LAYERNAME',
'concatenate', "mrid", filter:= intersects($geometry,end_point(geometry(@parent))))
```

*intersects is used in place of equals

** LAYERNAME is the SOURCE LAYER (point layer)

Comment: Very useful answer for first problem. Regarding  second part, I am trying to get the Start and End data of every line and save the attributes in new layer (Ignore the sequence in this case). Is that Possible with geomerty generator or any other method? Like this one 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXGln.png

Comment: Just add the second part

Comment: Can we use Virtual layer instead of iterating multiple algorithms? The purpose is to: connect lines and get the START POINT and END POINT of each line? Might be using `JOIN`, `ST_INTERSECTS(ST_STARTPOINT(c.geometry),n.geometry)`, `ST_INTERSECTS(ST_ENNDPOINT(c.geometry),n.geometry) `

Comment: I was also thinking about PyQGIS where the code will connect the points with lines and save the `STARTPOINT` and `ENNDPOINT` of lines in new layer.

Comment: Any idea, how we can deal with this kind of situation https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgofg.png . For instance, if I have only one point layer with 6 points. How can I connect a single node (cubicle146354)  with 5 other nodes ( service points) along with a substattion site as shown in the above Image. What I am trying to achieve here is : `connect nodes (point) with lines` and save the `Startpoint (FromNode)` to `Endpoint (ToNode)` data of every line  in new layer. The virtual layer should connect the lines and save the table similar to rightside of image.

Comment: My goal is to: `(1) connect node (cubicle146354) to other 5 nodes(service points),  (2) Connect substation_site (node) with  node (cubicle146354) with lines` . (3) Save the `Startpoint (FromNode)` and `Endpoint (ToNode)` data of connecting line in new layer as shown in rightsight table of image

Comment: The virtual layer should connect the lines and save the table similar to rightside of image https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgofg.png